# problems with subdomains and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a site, which I accept credit cards on. I bought an SSL for the subdomain secure.mywebsite.com. However, all of these bugs seem to be coming up and I believe they have to do with my changing subdomain.

Basically, what I want to have happen is all pages except the payment page should be http://www.mywebsite.com. Then, the payment page should be https://secure.mywebsite.com.

I keep running into issues where the user isn't signed in on secure.mywebsite.com. I tried adding :domain => :all to the session store config but that didn't work. What is the right way to handle this situation?

also, switching back and forth between www and secure doesn't seem to be working correctly.

lastly, when I go to sign out...going to secure.mywebsite.com/users/sign_out doesn't do anything like it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config/environments/production.rb turn force_ssl on to true

```
  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, 
  # and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true
```